# My arduino won't show up in Device Manager in any way, neither in unknown devices nor in COM port.

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a brand new arduino(original), and it is not showing up in Device manager or anywhere else. Even the computer doesn't Prompt anything. I am using Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable? Different computer?

Comment: Is there anything connected to it? (Like sensors and what not) that could be wired up wrong. Is the power light on?

Comment: It worked with a different cable.

Answer (score 1):

As the OP reported: *It worked with a different cable.*

I converted his comment to an answer so the system would regard this issue as solved. Please accept this answer.

---

Some cheap USB cables only carry power, and not data. I have such a cable that came with a USB desk light. To save money they only run two wires and not four, since the desk light is not a data device.

Be cautious about grabbing any old cable from your desk for testing. Make sure it is designed for data use. If in doubt, try a known good cable.